# How to prevent adding the same student's ID or numeric order in ListView?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a button **Add**. How can I prevent user from adding the same **student's ID** or the numeric order in ListView Control ?

My code just works when I keep Data in Textbox Control, but when I clear all Data and add same Data like before, it still can add.

This is my code.

```
 If LvSV.Items.Count = 0 Then
        Dim items As ListViewItem
        items = LvSV.Items.Add(Tbx_NumOrder.Text)
        items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_ID.Text)
        items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_Name.Text)
        items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_Class.Text)
        items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_hometown.Text)
        items = Nothing
    Else
        With LvSV
            Dim addIteam As ListViewItem
            Dim addIteam2 As ListViewItem
            addIteam = .FindItemWithText(Tbx_Name.Text, True, 0, True)
            'addIteam2 = .FindItemWithText(Tbx_ID.Text, True, 0, True)
            If Not addIteam Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("The student is already ", "Course List", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
            Else
               items = LvSV.Items.Add(Tbx_NumOrder.Text)
               items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_ID.Text)
               items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_Name.Text)
               items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_Class.Text)
               items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_hometown.Text)
               items = Nothing
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent adding duplicates? If so then start by thinking about how you would do it manually. If you had a list and an item to add to it, you'd first look at the list and check whether that item was already in the list, right? Why would it be any different in this case?

Comment: Exactly like you saying jmcilhinney , i just thinking simple is when i add id "01" and when i add "01" again , my code will find "01" in listview  if "01" have already , it will show notafication .

Comment: Please explain exactly what you expect to happen and what actually does happen. That's not just from a user's perspective either. Describe exactly what the code does on a line by line basis that is not what you expect. We shouldn't have to work it out for ourselves form code that doesn't work.

Comment: my english not good so when i describe maybe you don't understand. So  i want when i add same ID or NumOrder , the button "add" will  don't allow you add and have a notification " same ID or NumOrder" , this is exactly what i expect to happen . So can you  show me how to do with code or the keyword ?.

Comment: `Dim StudentIDStr as String = Tbx_ID.Text
For each Item in ListView.Items
If Item.Text = StudentIDStr then
MSG("Duplicate")
Exit For
End If
Next`

Comment: Or, if you use a datatable bound to a datagrid, this gets a bit easier..

Comment: it does still not work, somebody can show me the code or give me a keyword, pls?

Comment: You say that you "keep Data in Textbox Control". Do you then transfer it somewhere else, for example to a database? Are you asking how to check the database for the student's ID as well as checking the textbox control?

Comment: @ĐứcThắng Please provide more Information about your problems.

Comment: Guys i'm sorry for say not clearly , so this is what i need . How can i show the notification "  duplicate ID" when i add same id have already before in listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 lists of the values you have added for ID and Order Number instead of checking all the columns of the ListView for a match. Then use the .Contains method of the list to validate.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim lstID As New List(Of String)
    Dim lstOrdNum As New List(Of String)

    Private Function IsUnique() As Boolean
        If lstID.Contains(Tbx_ID.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate ID")
            Return False
        End If
        If lstOrdNum.Contains(Tbx_NumOrder.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Dublicate Order Number")
            Return False
        End If
        lstID.Add(Tbx_ID.Text)
        lstOrdNum.Add(Tbx_NumOrder.Text)
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub AddToListView()
        If IsUnique() Then
            Dim items As ListViewItem
            items = LvSV.Items.Add(Tbx_NumOrder.Text)
            items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_ID.Text)
            items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_Name.Text)
            items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_Class.Text)
            items.SubItems.Add(Tbx_hometown.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```